# How to stack sprites using collision detection on cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, sprite

I am a beginner on cocos2d an I'm looking for a way to stack 3 sprites one above another in cocos2d. I guess it would require collision detection but I could figure out a way to make it work. Does anybody has any idea that could help me out?

Comment: Are you just looking to set the position of 3 sprite so they're stacked?  I don't understand the collision detection part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather vague question without any code examples, but you can simply adjust the `position` parameters of your `CCSprite` objects so they are stacked on top of each other. If you used the dimensions of each sprite in your position formula, you can have it automatically know where each sprite is located and position the next one right above it.

Comment: The thing is that I am looking for a way to build a simple Hanoi Tower game and for that I'll need to stack the disks one above another. I have a specific sprite for each of them and I'm looking for a way to detect when the user stacks them to decide whether to allow the move or deny it and move the disk back to its place.